# Updating FrontEnd when there is a Change in Database Table

Tags: jsp

I am developing a Application using JSP , Servlets and MySQL as Database .

The FrontEnd is made of DOJO library JavaScript and JSP and it displays all the Elements Present in the Database Table .

One of our requirement is that whenever there is a change ( A New Entry that is added in the Table) , it should immediately reflect in the Front End .

This is not a Periodical refresh ,and  it may happen at anytime like after 1 Hour 2 Hours or even after 5 Hours )

Please sugget what is the best approach to deal with this requirement ??

Answer (score 0):

Actually you still need to periodically check if your db changes or not, then you can update your pages. To update it without user refreshing, try AJAX and polling.

For more details pls visit [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-dynamic-poll-with-jquery-and-php/).

Comment: @linmic: I think OP is using JSP and JavaScript and not PHP+JQuery. Although you are right in suggesting to use Ajax.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies (  I dont know PHP ) , is there any example with J2EE , rather than PHP for this ??

Comment: @harry-joy: I posted that which is becuz I believe he could understand "how to do" through the post, not just about PHP or JSP.

Comment: @user663724: http://blog.csdn.net/neusoftware_20063500/archive/2009/04/30/4140903.aspx this may help, though it's a Chinese webpage, you can translate this through Google Translate anyway. Cheers

Comment: @linmic: I know thats why I have not down voted you just said what I feel. One more thing don't write harry-joy it will not point to me. Just use harry or harry joy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time . You people have been very helpful .

Comment: @user663724: If you like answers than you should accept any one or upvote answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that shows demo of Ajax in jsp:

1. [ajaxprojects](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=580)
2. [ajax-programming-with-jsp-and-servlets](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/ajax/ajax-programming-with-jsp-and-servlets)
3. [w3schools Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp)
4. [roseindia Ajax](http://www.roseindia.net/software-tutorials/detail/17988)

Hope this helps.