# Auto-refresh table in jsp when data in Database is updated

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, server-push

My goal is to Extraction of Data From Database **Without** Refreshing Webpage.

When there is new data in database, you need to click refresh button or have a JavaScript to auto refresh the page to see the new data in jsp. However,

I would like my outcome to be like [this youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_7oYeNU_3g). However, this youtube used PHP. I am using JSP, SERVLET and Data Access Object where extraction of Data From Database **Without** Refreshing Webpage.

Can anymore please help me? Below are my codes. Help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance! :)

In **index.jsp**

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Menu</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${order}" var="item">
<tr>
<td>${item.fbMenuName}</td>
<td>${item.quantity}</td>
<td>${item.date}</td>
<td>${item.time}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In **servlet**

```
    OrderDAO od = new OrderDAO();

request.setAttribute("order", od.getPendingOrders(restaurant));
RequestDispatcher view =
     request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp"); view.forward(request,
     response);
```

In **OrderDAO**

```
public ArrayList getPendingOrders(String restaurant) {
                    Connection currentCon = null;       PreparedStatement ps = null;        ResultSet rs = null;

            ArrayList<OrderBean> listpendingorder = new ArrayList<OrderBean>();
            try {           currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
                Statement statement = currentCon.createStatement();             rs =
     statement.executeQuery("SELECT fbMenuName, quantity, date, time FROM
     orders");          while (rs.next()) {
                    OrderBean ob = new OrderBean();
                    ob.setFbMenuName(rs.getString("fbMenuName"));
                    ob.setQuantity(rs.getString("quantity"));
                    ob.setDate(rs.getString("date"));
                    ob.setTime(rs.getString("time"));
                    listpendingorder.add(ob);           }       } catch (SQLException e) {          e.printStackTrace();

                }

            return listpendingorder;    }
```

Comment: Your keyword is `server push`. Search in that way.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Hi, thanks! I am totally new in server push. I tried to google it. I managed to find [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11329233/3188711) . I do not know it is consider server push. Are you familiar with server push?

Comment: @newbieinjavaversion2 have look [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511208/updating-frontend-when-there-is-a-change-in-database-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511208/updating-frontend-when-there-is-a-change-in-database-table)